# Django: order formset without form change

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with only one field (name of family members).

```
class FamilyMemeberItem(forms.Form):
    name= forms.CharField(label=_('name'), max_length=20)
```

Now I want my form be sorted (arbitrary order) defined by the user. For example in a family, I want to show A first, then B and then C, while the creation sequence may be C, B and A. Is there anyway to do that?

I searched and realized I should add an `order` field to my form and override the `__iter__()` method. Is that the only way? If there is no way to do that without change in form?

And could anyone please tell me about the field `can_order` of `formset_factory`? When I add it, an extra filed is loaded next to my form, and that's and integer presenting the number of that field. Can I change and save that so that the order changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51082266/9225671) you posted.

I'll just repeat the last part here:

If you want to store the order in the database, you need to define a new field in you model and store the order in that. The order of formsets is only present inside a single request/response, after that its gone.